# Vertically align list element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see the sample code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJuaL

I am rendering hierarchical data in nested list elements. I used the browser default indentation for the list so that it is easy to see the hierarchy. I like to keep it that way (I may use css reset, and reapply). But I like to have the buttons on the right to be aligned vertically (means no shift between the button when look vertically). Is it possible with simple css. I use bootstrap as my framework.

code: (I used Jade to avoid the repetition)

```
oh_counties = [{name: "Franklin", zips:[111,222,333,444,555]},{name: "Adams", zips: [111,222,333,444]},{name: "Allen", zips: [111,222,333]}]

wi_counties = [{name: "Dane", zips: [111]},    {name: "Adams", zips: [111,222,333,444]}    ]

states = [{name: "OH", counties: oh_counties},{name: "WI", counties: wi_counties},]

mixin row(data)
  .row
    .col-lg-9
      if data.name
        | #{data.name} 
      else
        | #{data} 
    .col-lg-3
      button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type="button")
        | test

ul
  for st in states
    li
      +row(st)
      ul
        for c in st.counties
          li
            +row(c)
            ul
              for z in c.zips
                li
                  +row(z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to restructure your `row()` mixin and achieve what you are looking for.

```
mixin row(data)
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      if data.name
        | #{data.name} 
      else
        | #{data} 
      .pull-right
         button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type="button")
          | test
```

**Updated Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jervf

Comment: +1 Neil, that's neat. Will wait for just a bit to see any other approach, else will accept. thanks again for your help.